# Pythonic way of merging 2 lists of dicts based on common keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have 2 lists of dictionaries:

```
dict1 = [{"a":1, "b":2, "c":1295}, {"a":2, "b":5, "c":6274}, {"a":3, "b":1, "c":5337}]
```

and

```
dict2 = `[{"a":1, "b":2, "d":1884}, {"a":2, "b":5, "d":2049}, {"a":3, "b":3, "d":1086}]
```

The first list of dicts has the keys `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"`, while the second list has keys `"a"`, `"b"` and `"d"`.

I want to create a list of merged dicts having all 4 keys. Only the dicts with equal values for `"a"` and `"b"` need to be merged.

The expected result looks like this:

```
[{"a":1, "b":2, "c":1295, "d":1884}, {"a":2, "b":5, "c":6274, "d":2049}]
```

I am looking for a Pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: do the orders match up as in your example. Like are you trying to match `dict1[i]` with `dict2[i]` always?

Comment: That is the case, for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the merging-candidates from the two lists are the dicts from the same position, you can zip your lists together, employ a list comprehension and use the [`**`-syntax idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/3620003) for merging two dicts.

```
>>> dicts1 = [{"a":1, "b":2, "c":1295}, {"a":2, "b":5, "c":6274}, {"a":3, "b":1, "c":5337}]
>>> dicts2 = [{"a":1, "b":2, "d":1884}, {"a":2, "b":5, "d":2049}, {"a":3, "b":3, "d":1086}]
>>> 
>>> [{**d1, **d2} for d1, d2 in zip(dicts1, dicts2) if all(d1[k] == d2[k] for k in ('a', 'b'))]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1295, 'd': 1884},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 6274, 'd': 2049}]
```

---

Bonus `pandas` solution:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(dicts1)
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(dicts2)
>>> 
>>> df1
   a  b     c
0  1  2  1295
1  2  5  6274
2  3  1  5337
>>> 
>>> df2
   a  b     d
0  1  2  1884
1  2  5  2049
2  3  3  1086
>>> 
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['a', 'b']).to_dict(orient='records')
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1295, 'd': 1884},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 6274, 'd': 2049}]
```